# PHP Decoding JSON and Accessing Array Value based on dynamic variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, dynamic

I am trying to use a weather API for a project and I am trying to build a simple weather app that will check the forecast and display it. The code looks like this:

```
    $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=30553&appid={APIKEY}"; 
    $data = file_get_contents($url); 
    $decodeJSON = json_decode($data); 
    $testvar = "weather[0]->main";
    echo $decodeJSON->$testvar;
```

and ideally I would like to be able to change $testvar to point at different variables returned by the API and as of right now I know it can't be done by combining "$decodeJSON->" and "$testvar", but is there anyway to achieve something close to what I have above that basically just assembles the two?

Appreciate all the help in advance and any feedback on the code is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could, by using curly braces with the variable. you'd need to check for its existence to be sure though.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I updated it to "echo $decodeJSON->{$testvar};" and I am getting this error "[04-Aug-2020 03:54:17 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$weather[0]->main in /home/markwow/test.php on line 7" Is that what you were suggesting by adding the braces around it?

Comment: it won't work like that since it will be read as a literal string, the braces won't be interpreted as a sub level array instead. do you already know the properties / indices beforehand? you can just check it first, then print if it exists

Comment: "echo $decodeJSON->weather[0]->main" does resolve what I am looking for, but i was wondering if there was a way to keep it more open ended as the API returns a ton of weather information and I was hoping to turn this into a function to echo variables based on the sublevels provided

Comment: Then you will have to descend into this one level at a time, more or less recursively.